# For a list of items return the top 3 values based on their count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

For a given list of items in a column,I want it to give me top 3 values based on their count.

I would expect `Cat`, `Dog` and `Donkey` in another column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:A11, 
     "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A limit 3 label count(A) ''"), 
                 "select Col1")
```

*(You can adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using SQL you can get them using COUNT and then the fieldname.
If you are using a language not built around storing data you could run a for loop that updates a count variable for each element in the list.
ie:

```
    for (int i =0; i++; i < list.length) {
    if( list[i] == cat)
    catCounter++;
    if (list[i]) = dog)
    dogCounter++;
    .
    .
    .
    }
```