# Google Sheets Count Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For below given list of items in a column,I want it to give me top 3 values based on their count. I would expect Cat,Dog and Donkey in another column

Cat
Dog
Donkey
Rat
Cat
Dog
Cat
Donkey
Cat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For a list of items return the top 3 values based on their count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572945/for-a-list-of-items-return-the-top-3-values-based-on-their-count)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your list were in A2:A (with a header of some sort in A1). Use the following formula elsewhere (e.g., in B2):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:A,"Select A, COUNT(A) Where A Is Not Null Group By A Order By COUNT(A) Desc Limit 3 Label COUNT(A) ''"),"Select Col1")
```